# Need logging of TeamCity Build Triggers

Tags: logging, triggers, teamcity, teamcity-7.1

We use TeamCity 7.1 for continuous integration, and we produce build logs and artifacts for each build.  We created a special build trigger of our own.  It runs several times a day on several different configurations.  But every now and then it fails to initiate a build, and we are trying to determine why.  We want to log the output of the trigger itself.  Is it possible to generate a log from the build trigger, even if a build doesn't run as a result of the trigger?

Answer (score 1):

Our co-op posted to the jetbrains (the authors of TeamCity) message board about adding trigger logging .  It looks like there are a couple of options, outlined here: [TeamCity Build Trigger Logging](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5492840#5492840).

- Option 1 is to use log4j logging within the plugin itself
- Option 2 is to create our own logger

Comment: Thanks for taking time to post the solution.